# Issue with Paste Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I am having trouble continuing the paste ranges for my loop. Once it has completed one paste range it has trouble once I insert a new Paste range.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim nwbsht1 As Worksheet
    Dim nwbsht2 As Worksheet
    Dim nwbsht3 As Worksheet
    Dim nwbsht4 As Worksheet
    Dim nwbsht5 As Worksheet
    Dim nwbsht6 As Worksheet
    Dim nwbsht7 As Worksheet
    Dim nwbsht8 As Worksheet
    Dim rngToAbs As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Dim Onhand As Range
    Dim OnHand2 As Range
    Dim OnHand1 As Range
    Dim OnHand3 As Range
    Dim Pallet As Range
    Dim PalletType As Range
    Dim Item As Range
    Dim Item2 As Range
    Dim UnitQty As Range
    Dim CL As Range
    Dim DL As Range
    Dim OutputArray
    Dim I As Long
    
    
    
    'Setting ranges for PackPlan workbook
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    
       With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arils Pack Plan ")
        Set rngToAbs = .Range("F7:F28")
        Set Item = .Range("B7:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set PalletType = .Range("E7:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    
    'Opening Recent ATS report

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
    Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    End With

    'Setting Ranges for Daily Need Worksheet

    '4oz Range Setting

    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set nwbsht1 = nwb.Sheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    Set Onhand = nwbsht1.Range("Q5:Q14")

    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set nwbsht2 = nwb.Sheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    Set Pallet = nwbsht2.Range("E5:E14")

    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set nwbsht3 = nwb.Sheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    Set OnHand1 = nwbsht3.Range("U5:U14")

    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set nwbsht4 = nwb.Sheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    Set OnHand2 = nwbsht4.Range("Y5:Y14")
   

    '8oz Range Setting
    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set nwbsht5 = nwb.Sheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    Set OnHand3 = nwbsht5.Range("Q15:Q25")

    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set nwbsht6 = nwb.Sheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    Set Pallet = nwbsht6.Range("E15:E25")

    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set nwbsht7 = nwb.Sheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    Set OnHand1 = nwbsht7.Range("T15:T25")

    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set nwbsht8 = nwb.Sheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    Set OnHand2 = nwbsht8.Range("Y15:Y25")

    'Copy and Paste Loop for Units

    nwb.Activate

     I = 1
    ReDim OutputArray(1 To Onhand.Cells.Count)
    For Each CL In Onhand.Cells
        If CL.Value < 0 Then
            OutputArray(I) = CL.Value
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next CL

    wb.Activate
    wb.Sheets("Arils Pack Plan ").Range("F7").Resize(I, 1) = Application.Transpose(OutputArray)
  
  
  
  nwb.Activate

    ReDim OutputArray(1 To OnHand1.Cells.Count)
    For Each DL In OnHand1.Cells
        If DL.Value < 0 Then
            OutputArray(I) = DL.Value
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next DL
  
    wb.Activate
    wb.Sheets("Arils Pack Plan ").Range("F7").Resize(I, 1) = Application.Transpose(OutputArray)
```

Comment: Reset `I` to 1 before the 2nd loop

Comment: Wouldn't that make the paste range the same so it will paste over the previous range?

Comment: Where should the next paste be placed?

Comment: ...if you don't tell us what the code is *supposed* to do it's difficult to make useful suggestions.

Comment: I apologize. I want the code to be placed directly below the previous paste. So once it's done pasting information from one of the paste ranges. I want it to continue posting the data from other paste ranges below it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion for how you can do it (relevant parts only):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, colVals As Collection, v, arr, c As Range
    Dim nwb As Workbook, wsAPP As Worksheet, wsDNDR As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook           'ThisWorkbook?
    Set wsAPP = wb.Worksheets("Arils Pack Plan ") 'trailing space?
    
    'Opening Recent ATS report
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'user didn't pick a file
        Set nwb = Application.Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
    End With
    
    Set wsDNDR = nwb.Worksheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    
    Set colVals = New Collection
    'collect all of the negative values
    For Each c In wsDNDR.Range("Q5:Q14,E5:E14,U5:U14,Y5:Y14,Q15:Q25,E15:E25,T15:T25,Y15:Y25").Cells
        v = c.Value
        If v < 0 Then colVals.Add v
    Next c
    
    arr = CollectionToArray(colVals) 'transfer the collection values to an array
    If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then
        wsAPP.Range("F7").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), 1) = arr 'place the array on the sheet
    End If
  
End Sub

'return a 2D array ("column" format) with the values from a Collection
Function CollectionToArray(col As Collection)
    Dim arr, i As Long
    If col.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim arr(1 To col.Count, 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To col.Count
            arr(i, 1) = col(i)
        Next i
        CollectionToArray = arr
    Else
        CollectionToArray = Empty
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Will this run the ranges in order from the first range to the last?

Comment: Also, I am trying to use multiple versions of your For Each loop since I have to paste 4 of the ranges(E5:E14, E15:E25, Y5:Y14, Y15:Y25) in 2 different columns(B and E). Also, the values I am trying to paste are strings. Based on if the previous ranges (Q5:Q14, Q5:Q14, T5:T14, T15:T25) are negative. So I tried to create 2 other ranges and add those strings to the new ranges and paste them in the proper columns in the Arils pack plan sheet.

Comment: Yes, it will run though the ranges in order (you can test that by adding `Debug.Print c.Address` in the loop)  You'll need to use different loops if you have different criteria for copying.

Comment: I attempted to but, I am having issues with the loops.

Comment: Can you create a new post, with your current code and a description of exactly what's going wrong when you run it?

Comment: Okay I posted the code I currently have a with a description and the issues.